# Are there any clear limits of JavaScript in relation to manipulating the browser and DOM?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, google-chrome, firefox-addon

I heard that getting access to the text a Gmail email is very  difficult if not impossible (iframes).

Are there certain areas where JavaScript is not capable of doing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframes won't prevent you from accessing content. JavaScript doesn't really have any limits with regards to manipulating the DOM....it can't, however, access stuff on your computer, or be used to upload files and such. It can't read stuff inside flash files either. You don't really have any choices other than JS anyway.. what kind of road blocks are you anticipating?

Comment: Regarding roadblocks, I'm still a bit hazy on that. I'm interested in something like a mini "text editor" within the browser. Or possibly saving/interacting with browser history extensively.

Comment: A mini text editor is very doable. ckeditor would be one example http://ckeditor.com/. Browser history, I think you have limited access to. Browsers generally limit what information you have access to so you don't go stealing people's personal information and screwing up their settings.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've chosen to use [firefox-addon](/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) tag: no, getting access to Gmail text is unproblematic from an add-on. Doing the same from a regular website however isn't possible unless that website is hosted on mail.google.com. Reason is a security mechanism called [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Websites are generally limited by the same-origin policy, add-ons are not.

Comment: Thanks very much - I'm reading up on same-origin policy right now!

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers have different limitations that they impose on JavaScript as well as different APIs that they provide to JavaScript to grant it access to different forms of data. Until recently, it was not possible for JavaScript to access local files; however, there  are now APIs in some browsers to do this.

There is a concept known as the "same origin" policy that is used to ensure that JavaScript running from the context of one domain or protocol cannot access data from another domain or protocol. However, browser add-ons or extensions can often exempt themselves from these restrictions. Also, some browsers provide APIs specifically for communication between different origins; however, these APIs generally require that this is done with the cooperation and permission of both origins.

Comment: This is really interesting - I didn't know that  browser add-ons or extensions circumvent the restrictions. Cool! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

From extension JS, you can access any part of Gmail. I wrote a browser extension that allowed me to forward a Gmail email to a Facebook contact. It also appeared in Facebook and allowed me to send Facebook message to Gmail contact. It was so that I didn't need to worry about adding contacts from Google to Facebook and vice versa.

That extension was easy. Once you get passed the iframe piece, it is cake. Good luck!

Comment: Wow! That browser extension you mention sounds really cool. Is it available for download to us? I think you can bank real moolah on it!

Comment: How could I make bank on it? If you are right, I will polish it up and get it out there. For now, I just built it for me and my friends to use.

Comment: He can't bank on it. Facebook has email now in case you haven't noticed. You have your own @facebook email address. Also, you can easily add all your Google contacts to Facebook with their import feature.